# Erro entre Contextos do Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Estou usando dois contextos do Entity Framework, um para o
Identity (que está na camada de cross cutting) e outro para minha aplicação (na camada de Data), ambos apontam para o mesmo banco.

Camada de Data:

```
public class IdentityIsolationContext : DbContext
{
    public IdentityIsolationContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; } //Fala que já existe essa tabela, mas eu gostaria que atualizasse...
    public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; } // Não gera a tabela
    public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; } // Não gera a tabela

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UsuarioConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProdutoConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CategoriaConfig());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Camada de Cross Cutting:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IDisposable
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

No meu domínio criei uma classe Usuario com os mesmos campos
da tabela "AspNetUsers" do Identity (e mais dois campos: nome e ativo) e, com Fluent Api, configurei a classe para ser mapeada para "AspNetUsers", e assim posso acessar a tabela "AspNetUsers" como se fosse uma entidade do domínio. Abaixo as configurações:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; } // Novo campo

    public bool Ativo { get; set; } // Novo campo

    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }

    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }

    public virtual bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }

    public virtual bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }

    public virtual int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Tentei deixar com as mesmas configurações da tabela original:

```
public class UsuarioConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioConfig()
    {
        HasKey(u => u.Id);

        Property(u => u.Nome)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        Property(u => u.Email)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256);

        Property(u => u.UserName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256);

        ToTable("AspNetUsers");
    }
}
```

Só que ao dar um Update-Database no IdentityIsolationContext ele tenta criar a tabela "AspNetUsers" e, com isso, gera um erro pois já existe essa tabela. Só que eu queria que ele atualizasse e não tentasse criar
outra tabela. 
E percebi também, que mesmo adicionando outras classes na IdentityIsolationContext não é criada nenhuma tabela para elas e também nenhum campo adicionado, mas no ApplicationDbContext qualquer alteração é refletida normalmente.
Não queria colocar as entidades do meu negócio no contexto do Identity.

Comment: Creio que na camada Cross Cutting não é necessário criar as tabelas novamente, siga o exemplo:

https://github.com/EduardoPires/IdentityIsolation

Comment: Olá Lucas, estou seguindo esse exemplo mesmo, não coloquei nada na cross cutting, somente na Infra.Data mesmo, porém como disse o EF lança o problema que citei acima quando coloco as entidades na camada de Data..

Answer (score 0):

Tive esse problema alguns anos atrás. Pelo que eu lembro, a solução foi fazer o "mapeamento" direto no DbContext, utilizando o metodo OnModelCreating.

Por algum motivo, o EF não consegue fazer isso quando o "mapeamento" está numa classe "externa".

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");


            #region User
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Id)
                .HasColumnOrder(10)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasMaxLength(128);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.AccessFailedCount)
                .HasColumnOrder(20);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Active)
                .HasColumnOrder(30);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Email)
                .HasColumnOrder(50)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasMaxLength(256);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.EmailConfirmed)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnOrder(60);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.LockoutEnabled)
                .HasColumnOrder(70);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.LockoutEndDateUtc)
                .HasColumnOrder(80);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Name)
                .HasColumnOrder(90)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasMaxLength(256);


            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.PasswordHash)
                .HasColumnOrder(100);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.PhoneNumber)
                .HasColumnOrder(110)
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasMaxLength(15);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                .HasColumnOrder(120);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.SecurityStamp)
                .HasColumnOrder(130);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.TwoFactorEnabled)
                .HasColumnOrder(140);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.UserName)
                .HasColumnOrder(150)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .HasMaxLength(256)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IdxUserName") { IsUnique = true }));



            #endregion
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Nereu, mas continua dando a mesma coisa. E também dessa forma iria ficar gigante o OnModelCreating.